# Expanding over multiple input files in snakemake rule

Tags: snakemake

I want to create a table of file paths that come from a list of datasets. I am able to get this rule to execute properly whenever `len(dataset_list) < 7` but I get the error `Missing files after 5 seconds:` whenever `len(dataset_list) >= 7`. Here is a minimal example of my rule:

```
# cases that work since they have len()<7
# dataset_list = ['D2.0', 'D2.1', 'D2.2', 'D2.3', 'D2.4', 'D2.5']
# dataset_list = ['D2.0', 'D2.1', 'D2.2', 'D2.3', 'D2.4', 'D2.6']
# dataset_list = ['D2.0', 'D2.1', 'D2.2', 'D2.3', 'D2.5', 'D2.6']

# including 7 or more datasets causes a failure no matter what they are
# dataset_list = ['D2.0', 'D2.1', 'D2.2', 'D2.3', 'D2.4', 'D2.5', 'D2.6']
dataset_list = ['D1.0', 'D1.1', 'D1.2', 'D1.3', 'D1.4', 'D1.5', 'D1.6']
rule aggregate_model_results:
    input: 
        cn1 = expand(
            'analysis/{dataset}/cn1.tsv',
            dataset=dataset_list
        ),
        cn2 = expand(
            'analysis/{dataset}/cn2.tsv',
            dataset=dataset_list
        ),
        cn3 = expand(
            'analysis/{dataset}/cn3.tsv',
            dataset=dataset_list
        )
    output: 'analysis/all/file_paths.tsv'
    params:
        datasets = expand(dataset_list)
    run:
        df = []
        for dataset, cn1_path, cn2_path, cn3_path in zip(
                params.datasets, input.cn1, input.cn2, input.cn3
            ):
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame({
                'dataset': [str(dataset)], 'cn1_path': [str(cn1_path)],
                'cn2_path': [str(cn2_path)], 'cn3_path': [str(cn3_path)]
            })
            df.append(temp_df)
        df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_csv(str(output), sep='\t', index=False)
```

I have manually verified that all of these input files are present and not corrupted. I also attempted to only expand over `cn1` and `cn2` input files (excluding `cn3`) and got the same error whenever `len(dataset_list)>10`. Given this behavior, I'm lead to think that there's somehow a maximum limit of 20 total input files for this rule; however, such a constraint doesn't seem to apply to my `rule all` at the top of this `.smk` file which takes in >20 input files expanded over >100 datasets. This error has persisted when I increase the `--latency_wait_time` so that's not the issue. Any idea on what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.
-Adam

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Your script runs ok on my machine.

Comment: Hm do you think it's possible that there's a limit on the number of target files (or total character limit on target files) within an entire `.smk` file? There are >2000 jobs that get executed in this pipeline upstream of `rule aggregate_model_results`.

Comment: You can always test that by yourself. The script you provide in the question works.